# kittens are biting everything... literally

Tags: cats, behavior, health, biting, chewing

SO my cats are excessive biters.  wall corners, the plastic window shades you have in most apartments, my metal towel holder, cardboard boxes, any food in plastic bags or wrappers on the counters such as a loaf of bread, and many of my electronic devices such as headphones and charging cables for my iphone, apple watch, and mac book pro.

I know when I got the kittens, they were very young at 4 weeks (yea that's a whole other story), and I have been waiting for them to grow out of this destructive phase (they have also destroyed some things like the cap to the side overflow drain in the bathtub) but it seems to be never ending at almost 9 months old now.  Even bit the glass lip off of my beer bottle while I was in another room.

I have tried everything from coating the wires in that bitter spray to providing them enough toys that it is a mine field to walk around.  They have dry food out 24/7 regulated by 2 small bowls that usually last them a little more than a day before I refill.  I do also feed them their wet food as well so they should be getting a balanced diet.  They don't scare very easily if at all.  Any attempts to clap or do pennies in a can doesn't even pique their interest as they continue the behaviors.  They are also extremely aggressive when I am eating food more so than any other cat I have had.  Usually after a few times of putting them down off the table or away from where ever it is I am eating, the cats will lose interest and walk off.  These 2 guys however, will try to "outsmart" me by coming at different angles, or different sides of the table, or come up behind other objects thinking I can't see them and it will turn dinner into a 15 minute game of keep away.

Is there something  more I can do? is this an issue I should talk to the vet about? I have previously brought it up to the vet while getting them their kitten shots but they kind of dismissed the subject or provided solutions I have already tried.  I have put wires I don't use away in a drawer where they cannot access it, but for my phone I charge over night, I have been waking up to them chewing on it in the middle of the night.  I don't want to lock them out of my bedroom but I also cannot have my phone where I won't hear it due to my job.  I would like to stop the behavior rather than just find a temporary solution like hiding the wires.  Would getting something like cat grass help?  dog chew toys?

Also to add... I have been using the spray bottle pretty heavily since they were young.  It is to the point all I have to do is show them it and they stop doing what ever it is they are doing.  They also know what they are doing is wrong because when I hear them up to something and they hear me walking into the room they are in, they instantly scatter.  So my cats are aware that when they are doing certain behaviors that a consequence is coming.  They just, try to get away with it like any other kid I suppose lol  But that is the other odd thing is that they are NOT afraid of water.  They practically shower with me every morning sitting on the side of the bathtub.  As far as what breed they are in case it matters, they were advertised as a maine coon mix that I adopted from a shelter.  However when taken to the vet, they are just short haired domestics and they do not show any physical traits of a maine coon anyways.

They are very loving playful cats.  Some of the most loving cats I have had.  My female loves to be cradled in my arms like a baby for hours while I am working at the computer and my male will often jump up and lay on my arm or curl up on the inner part of my arm if they are extended.  Both are very bonded to me and will follow me every where I go and my female even puts her paws on the side of my leg like dogs do when I come home from work.  Even my mom commented on how attached the cats are to me as well.  They really are great, cute, and friendly cats that everyone loves when ever they visit my place.  It's just this destructive kick they have that I don't know how else to put an end to it.

Comment: welp, just woke up to my cable I just bought last weekend being dead.  I understand they are kittens or just teething, but this honestly seems to be an issue.  I have never seen cats chew on things like this.  Every cat I have previously had, been 4+ months when we adopted so I have experienced this stage plenty of times and never have I had any of them destroy this much if anything at all.

Comment: My cat used to chew on any type of cable when he was young, he cost me 2 Xbox headsets and 3 PC headsets (expensive ones). He eventually grew out of this, but i always had to hide my cables. Wrapping them in towels and other type of protectors

Comment: @Vahx yes, I have already tallied quite the list of dead electronics.  Well over 1000 dollars worth of equipment lol  Not that I am saying money is more important than my cats (because I know some reader will say something like "don't get cats if you care more about your things").  I have resorted to hiding all my cables in my bedroom drawers for now.  I hope mine grow out of it too.  At almost a year now, I haven't seen cats chew up wires at this stage of growth so I find the behavior to be a bit odd.  Then again, Previously I haven't been gone 12 hours a day either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, having a Vet examine their teeth is a good idea, regardless. First of all, it will help prevent any future dental issues. Second, it will keep an eye on current progress of tooth growth and ensure that the "baby" teeth are departing correctly. This should be pretty frequent during the growth of their teeth.

In the meanwhile, if they are teething, you may want to stick with soft foods and get a teething toys for them, especially ones that you can chill down. Similar to human babies, the chill of the teething toys can help reduce discomfort. I also think your challenges have been exacerbated by the early adoption, but finding them acceptable chewing toys may help. Spray bottle won't do much, it's short-lived effectiveness, but make sure you discourage any biting of people, it will carry on otherwise.

Comment: Yes, they do not bite humans at all unless playing which is usually initiated by the human and they don't mind the playful nibbles.  This biting is mostly with objects.  I will definitely give chilling toys a try.  What about cat grass?  Give them something they can chew on that is for them?  I will also try to add water to their dry food to see if that helps.  yea unfortunatey this lady i adopted from had no idea how to really take care of cats just that "she loved cats" and when I saw the conditions they were in and her lack of real knowledge, I decided to take them early and do it myself.

Comment: Cat grass will give you the added bonus of needing to clean up cat vomit... I would avoid for now. Stick with things they won't swallow. :)